# shell script to loop through wildcard matched directories

Tags: linux, shell, loops, for-loop, directory

I am trying to loop through directories that match a wildcard. This works fine in command line. But does not work in Shell script. Any idea?

```
   for dirs in /var/www/html/my.domain.com/v*; do echo $dirs; done;
```

The above command lists

```
  /var/www/html/my.domain.com/v1.0
  /var/www/html/my.domain.com/v1.2
  /var/www/html/my.domain.com/v2.0
```

Here is the Shell script version. Its not working:

```
 dirs=/var/www/html/my.domain.com/v*
 for dir in $dirs
 do
   echo "$dir"
 done
```

Tried this too:

```
dirs=`/var/www/html/my.domain.com/v*` #back quotes
for dir in $dirs
do
   echo "$dir"
done
```

Comment: the example just works for me - without any quoting. Are you using `shopt` somewhere before in this script?

Comment: Further note, that quoting using backticks will start a subshell and return its ouput. So, in backticks only commands are meaningful

Comment: @hek2mgl No. Just some  other code. But nowhere used `shopt`

Comment: is the first line of you shell script `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Tried without quotes too. But no luck.

Comment: @hek2mgl No. Its not there.

Comment: how do you start the script?

Comment: I run it by `sh script.sh`

Comment: Without quote, I just get the same line as is `/var/www/html/my.domain.com/v*`

Comment: I use some sudo commands inside the script. Should I be using that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Glob patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) like `/var/www/html/my.domain.com/v*` are a **bash** feature. It seems that bash is not the default shell on your system as you started the script using `sh script.sh`.

Make sure that you start the script using bash:

```
bash script.sh
```

If you are about to make the script executable directly using `chmod +x script.sh`, make sure that you are not missing to use the following [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) in the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```